# ReactNative unlink not working with react-native-push-notification?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Recently I added [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) to my react native project and this error appears when project startup.

> `> react-native run-android`

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-push-notification (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-push-notification")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward,
you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your
app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and
notify the library maintainers.
```

I used unlink command and it says successfully unlinked, but error doesn't disappear. I manually checked in those files too,

```
android>settings.gradle
```

```
android>app>build.gradle
```

Comment: Try deleting the node modules and then installing them again.

Comment: @harshitraghav I have done it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your gradle as well?

Comment: yeah. I cleaned that too.